# background-image in div – Google indexing?

Tags: css, image, indexing, background-image

I've a list of empty divs and dynamically inserting a background image – so at first, their background-image: url(); property is completely empty. With some event, it's background-image url loads into the previously empty background-image: url(); tag. The url of the appearing background-image is temporarily stored in the "alt" tag of the div:

`<div style='background-image: url();' alt='http://something...'></div>`.

I'm doing so to get round corners on several animated gifs without using transparent gifs (no smooth edges).

Question: does Google robots index those images? I could imagine they do because the url is already stored in the html code and not in some external css-file, however not as "img" tag but as "alt" or "something" tag!?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [How does "background: url(image.ext)" work from an SEO standpoint?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71032/how-does-background-urlimage-ext-work-from-an-seo-standpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Paolo's answer is correct in general, but some bots *might* look for any kind of image resource referenced in the page - it's not unthinkable, and certainly not unethical.

If you want to make sure no search engine indexes the images, you can set up your [**robots.txt**](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to block them.

If you want to make sure bots *do* index them, you could for example set up a page containing `<img>` tags with all the images, and put an innocuous link to that page onto your front page.

Comment: True, the caveat was "most" :)

Comment: @Paolo yeah. It's perfectly possible they don't index images like that at all. It's just that I have seen pages and sub-sites on my own sites pop up in Google I was 100% sure I have never referenced anywhere that I have grown the general feeling that the Google bot is very greedy :)

Comment: I will try to set up a page containing all the <img> tags, as you suggested.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Googlebot (like most spiders) does not attempt to run javascript, so the only things it will index are the things appearing in the original HTML downloaded from the server.  Any subsequent manipulation by JQuery just won't happen.

Also - most spiders don't index CSS either so background-images will also be ignored for that reason.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. If Bots run javascript or not is not the problem. But do you know, if Bots index image-urls which are not in "href" or "src" tags but in the "alt" or some tag of a div?
Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Paolo, can you name some of the search engines that do index CSS? On the other hand is it fair to say that Google inspects your css to ensure webmaster guidelines are not being violated? Trying to make the distinction between Google indexing a css file vs. inspecting it.

Comment: Googlebot is now known to run and index javascript content.

Answer (score 1):

Googlebots will certainly index IMG ALT attributes.  Whether or not they subsequently detect the fact that alt texts contain URLs and go looking at them, I really don't know.

This seems to me an abuse of the alt attribute, frankly: DIVs shouldn't (don't) have ALT attributes, and even if they did, this is not what they are for.