# force google to index javascript background images

Tags: javascript, meta

I have some background images load via javascript, so the div or the container is empty on load, can i use some meta to let google know and index those images?
it would be useful if i can also associate a label

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible - some googling also helped: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319201/background-image-in-div-google-indexing)